# EWS: SearchFilter not working in case of MS Teams

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, microsoft-teams

EWS Search filter not working for team in MS Teams. While it is working for 1 to 1 and group chat message.

We are retrieving messages from MS Teams. The edited messages are stored in revision folder.

We start by fetching message from Team Chat folder. 
Then, for each message, we search the message into the Recoverable Items\Version by ConversationId but it is returning empty result.

We have actually verified that message with that `conversationId` is present in the revision folder using EWS Editor but search is return it.

Notes here: the same code is working for 1 to 1 and group conversation.

```
SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.ConversationId, "33333333");
ItemView view = new ItemView(50);
view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending);
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = _exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.RecoverableItemsVersions,
    searchFilter, view);
```

[image: Team Chat Folder]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In MsTeams, the 1 to 1 and group conversation are stored in user mail box while team conversation will have separate mailbox which contains all teams message. Actually, we were trying to find in user mailbox so hence we did not find. After we searched in the team's mailbox, we got the result from SearchFilter as expected.